# Why the Mongodb queries become slowly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I setup a Java web application project which is based on MongoDB. The DAO of the this project is implemented by MongoDB Java driver; I didn't use the Spring Data for MongoDB.

I'm getting a performance problem. If the application sends a query to the database, the response time is about 17ms. But if I used the Jmeter -- which mocked about 300 users -- the response time of 90%Line is about 1300ms. The response time is intolerable. I tried to find the reason, but I don't know.

Also, there is the `MongoUri` String:

```
mongo.uri=mongodb://192.168.1.172:27017,192.168.1.172:22222,192.168.1.172:33333/?replicaSet=yyyy&maxPoolSize=100&ssl=false&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&connectTimeoutMS=10000&socketTimeoutMS=10000&safe=false&
```

The query is just like a query for an `objectID`, like `db.collection.find( { _id: xxxx } )`. Also, I've constructed the index on `_id`.

mongo.xml

```
<bean id="uri" class="com.mongodb.MongoClientURI">
<constructor-arg value="${mongo.uri}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoClient" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
<constructor-arg ref="uri"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCollectionDao" class="com.xxx.api.domain.dao.impl.MongoCollectionDao" lazy-init="false">
<constructor-arg name="mongoClient" ref="mongoClient"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg name="mongoDatabaseName" value="${mongo.database}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Could anyone explain what's going wrong here?

Comment: It will certainly help to see some of your code. And what is "90%Line"?

Comment: Thanks Keith. I add a piece of java code. but I don't know why i can't post the content of mong.xml.

Comment: I edited the info from your comments into the question, please read over them to ensure that I transcribed the info accurately!